# Getting rid of "tree darkness"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you've played Minecraft in the early beta versions, and then updated to beta 1.8+ you might have noticed that the trees looked pretty different. Here is an example of a pre beta-1.8 tree:

[image: tree1]

Now here's a picture of a beta-1.8+ tree:

[image: tree2]
<sub>(source: [weebly.com](https://willardcomputer20121alexp.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/0/6/14068120/4419668.jpg?433))</sub>

In the beta-1.8+ picture of a tree, you might notice that the more leaf blocks you have surrounding one leaf block, the surrounded leaf block will be darker. Personally, I'm not a big fan of this, which is why I'm asking if there is anyway to get rid of it. So, is there anyway to get rid of it?

Also, I'm not completely sure if it was beta 1.8 when these tree changes took place, after all, it was two+ years ago. If I did get this wrong, and it was added In a later update, please do tell.

Comment: Also, I'm not very good a formatting questions, so feel free to edit my question if neccesary.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your broken images. (Pending peer review). But isn't that just a different type of tree? Perhaps there's something my eye is not catching.

Comment: @Hello_World All I noticed is that prior to beta 1.8, if you surrounded a leaf block with others leaves, nothing happens. In beta 1.8+ if you surround a leaf block with other leaves, the leaf in the center gets darker than the surrounding leaf blocks.

Comment: Wild guess, but try turning smooth lighting off. If that doesn't work: you might very well be out of luck, since the lighting engine in he game has changed quite a bit since back then.

Comment: Leaves do reduce the light that shines through them. There is also the fact that you compare small, round, bright tree to a large, tiered, spruce tree in a blueish-hue biome. Try looking at a small oak in Plains, and see if it fixes the impression.

Comment: @Orc_JMR I will fix the pictures and compare the oak to an oak.

Comment: @Orc_JMR Feel free to edit my question, I think if broke the second picture because I suck at question formatting.

Comment: @Hello_World I edited my question so it's comparing an oak tree to an oak tree. I also broke the second picture again.

Comment: You're still comparing different biomes though. I believe a Forest biome would be the most similar to pre-Beta 1.8 coloring. The fact that outer leaves shade inner leaves simply follows the real world, however. I would imagine the only way to get this look again would be to play in pre-Beta 1.8.

Comment: Try making a Creative Mode world and you can place leaves wherever you want.  This guarantees that they are the same type.  Then you can have 1 picture with an example of both setups you are asking about.

Comment: @Johonn Or play minecraft PE, which still hasn't added the tree sharing yet. Although, as mentioned, I haven't tried turning off smooth lighting, which for all I know could help.

Comment: @Johonn I think this effect also takes place regardless of which biome the tree is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lighting engine changed in 1.8. There is no way to revert this, other than reverting your entire game to Beta 1.7.3.

Comment: Or using mods who basically undo the change.